# Несколько дубликатов к вопросу - "законно" ли?

Tags: обсуждение, дубликаты

"Законно" ли закрывать вопрос, если предложены разные дубликаты?

Пример: [Абстрактный List с интерфейсом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/742406/218063)

Что получается, вопрос закрывается, когда набирается пять пометок о дубликате, но ссылки на дубликаты могут быть разные, из-за этого на плашке будут перечислены несколько похожих (или не очень) ответов.

Таким образом, увеличивается сила голоса закрывающего, т.е. если есть четыре голоса за дубликат и следующий голосующий выберет другой дубликат - получается, что он единолично вынес это решение и система его одобрила.

Comment: Голосую за переоткрытие. Причина: [посмеялись](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3H8Hx.png) и хватит.

Comment: Да смысл переоткрывать? Удалять надо)

Comment: @vp_arth, зачем удалять? Здесь был проведён важный эксперимент по определению условий появления плашки множественного дубля.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2C4Z.png

Answer (score 6):

Этот список всегда можно править. Это могут делать обладатели золотого знака по метке и модераторы. Даже если лишний вопрос попадёт в список дубликатов, не думаю, что это страшно. А кто-нибудь потом поправит, если понадобится.

[image: скриншот]

[image: скриншот правки]

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Ух ты, только сейчас заметил кнопку "править"! А ведь кто-то считал вопрос бесполезным...

Comment: @PavelMayorov [Вы не одиноки](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=39878198#39878198)